# Get different output from the end of a method chain

Tags: javascript, method-chaining

If i have a method-chain that looks something like this:

```
object.value.add(1).multiply(2);
```

And the object is this:

```
var object = {
    "value":1,
    "add":function(x){
        this.value = this.value + x;
        return this;
    },
    "multiply":function(x){
        this.value = this.value * x;
        return this;
    }
}
```

This would output:

```
{
    "value":4,
    "add":function(x){
        this.value = this.value + x;
        return this;
    },
    "multiply":function(x){
        this.value = this.value * x;
        return this;
    }
}
```

But i want it to output:

```
4
```

Is this possible? 
And i don't want to make another method for the output, i want the "multiply" method (and the "add" method) to multiply the entire object if it's not the last in the method-chain (so that method-chaining is possible), but when it's last i want it to output the "value" attribute.

Comment: These kind of patterns need a way to signal the end. Something like an `equals()` method.

Comment: It's not directly possible. A function doesn't know whether it is part of a chain or not. There are only hacks to make this work by coercing the object into a primitive value.

Comment: add an optional boolean as last parameter of your methods and if provided you return this.value instead of this

Comment: It would be pretty non-intuitive to have methods transition between intermediate and terminal operations based on their location in the method-chain. It certainly makes for a non-reliable contract to have the method sometimes return an object and sometimes return a number. As @MarkMeyer mentioned, adding a terminal `equals()` method to your API is the cleanest approach (and is typical with this pattern).

Comment: What do you mean with an equals() method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no efficient way (there might not even be a way) for the method to know if it is the last member of the chain.

Why not this?

```
object.add(1).multiply(2).value
```

You could also leverage `valueOf` in very specific scenarios, but it cannot be leveraged as a general purpose strategy to that end.

```js
var object = {
    "value":1,
    "add":function(x){
        this.value = this.value + x;
        return this;
    },
    "multiply":function(x){
        this.value = this.value * x;
        return this;
    },
    valueOf: function () { return this.value; }
};

console.log(object.add(4).multiply(2) / 2); //5
```